# kendo scheduler not respecting client timezone when sending to controller on azure

Tags: asp.net-mvc, datetime, azure, kendo-ui, kendo-scheduler

I am having an interesting problem with my deployment of a kendo-ui scheduler to Windows Azure.  When I create a new event it correctly calls the Create action on my controller.  The difference comes in the Start and End times when I deploy to an Azure instance.  My client browser is running in Eastern time (EST) while Azure is running in UTC time.  My research tells me the scheduler converts the Start/End times from the client time to UTC before sending to the server.  That is not happening for me.  I am getting the local time sent with a UTC "kind".  For example, if I create an event at 5pm on my local browser on Eastern time it arrives at Azure with a UTC time of 5pm instead of a UTC time of 10pm.  When I run the server locally it correctly sends the start time as 10pm in UTC.

I have tried many things with no luck.  Including setting the Timezone of the scheduler to the timezone of the client.

> @(Html.Kendo().Scheduler()
>                       .Timezone((string)ViewBag.TimeZone)

Is there some setting or an elegant solution that I have missed in the documentation and other postings here?

Any responses appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this will be helpful -> http://www.telerik.com/support/code-library/using-utc-time-on-both-client-and-server-sides

Comment: Very interesting.  I had hoped for a more elegant solution like a setting in Kendo but this will do.  I had a kludge in my server code that adjusted the time based upon what I knew of the user's timezone.  This is a more intelligent answer in that it automatically adjusts to the time of the user's machine.  That means any complications from Daylight Savings Time and traveling are automatically handled.  Thanks!